# Combine two lists into csv

Tags: csv, sh

I have two files, a.txt and b.txt. Let's say:

`a.txt` contains:

```
123
234
345
456
```

and `b.txt` contains:

```
012
023
034
045
```

I need to combine them into the following:

```
123,012
234,023
345,034
456,045
```

Any idea on how can I do it in basic sh?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be to use the [`paste`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/) command.

```
$ paste -d"," a.txt b.txt
123,012
234,023
345,034
456,045
```

Answer (score 1):

As Shawn points out, `paste` is definitely the correct tool to use.  If you want to do it strictly in the shell:

```
while read a; read -u 3 b; do echo $a,$b; done < a.txt 3< b.txt
```